# Xamarin iOS GoogleMobileAds package No matching framework found inside

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

After updating to VS 17.3.6 (Xamarin.iOS Version: 16.0.0.72) I'm getting the following error when trying to build the app for the Simulator. It does work on a physical device.

> /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/iOS/Xamarin.Shared.targets(3,3): Error: No matching framework found inside '/Users/xxx/Library/Caches/XamarinBuildDownload/FAdM-8.13.0/Frameworks/GoogleMobileAdsFramework-Current/GoogleMobileAds.xcframework'.
> SupportedPlatform: 'ios', SupportedPlatformVariant: 'simulator', SupportedArchitectures: 'i386, x86_64'.

I've tried deleting the obj and bin folders.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: I had a similar issue and the reason was a too long path of the nuget package inside the .nuget folder. I solved it relocating the nuget packages from C:\Users\XXX\.nuget to C:\nuget. You can find it how googling around.

Comment: @AndreaGobs are you on windows or mac? i think your suggestions is for windos

Comment: Yes, on Windows

Comment: Any solution for mac? Getting same issue on mac